# I am not getting the label text as if modified in textarea..how can i get that?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a textarea and will modify the text like bold,italic,text-color.. now when i click a button i am extracting the text from textarea.now problem is the text is not visible as modified text...the simple text is seen...so what should i do to get the modified text same in label generated...

```
function createLabel()
{
    var text=document.getElementById("heading");
    var textVal=text.value;
    var label=document.getElementById("LabelShow");
    label.innerHTML=textVal;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard HTML `<textarea>` only works with plain text - any formatting you apply to the control is for presentation only and doesn't affect the text returned. If you want to edit rich text in a web page then you need to use a control such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).